# Cannot switch FaceTime call to iPhone after initiating it on my Mac

Tags: iphone, mac, continuity

I initiated a call on my MacbookPro (running OS X Yosemite), but I cannot transfer it to my iPhone while it's in progress, as advertised on the Continuity feature.

The [Apple Support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18756) says:

> Transfer the call to your iPhone: Unlock your iPhone, then tap the “Touch to return to call” banner at the top of the screen on your iPhone.

When I unlock my iPhone 6 Plus (running iOS 8.1), however, no banner appears at the top of the screen, and my phone seems to completely ignore the presence of a call.

Since there are no troubleshooting steps listed on the Apple Support guide for this issue, is there any way to troubleshoot this issue or to fix it?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.cultofmac.com/297221/continuity-handoff-ios-8-os-x-yosemite/ It mentions the respective settings you have to have set up on both of your devices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The continuity is only for cellular calls, which are routed through the iPhone, but doesn’t work with facetime calls.

FaceTime would have to just be configured on both devices and you pick up directly without needing a hand-off from one ringing to cause the other to ring.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open Phone app on your iPhone, you must see the banner and will be able to return to call.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest upgrading both devices to the lates versions of OS/iOS, or at least your iPhone. This will probably resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If after configuring both the Mac and the iOS device correctly per the support linked article below, it still doesn't work, sign out of iCloud first on the Mac and then re-sign in and see if it attempts to re-establish the continuity through iCloud.

If that doesn't work, sign out of iCloud on both the Mac and iOS device(s) and re-login and ensure all configurations are correct per this Apple Support document:

- [Make and receive calls on your Mac, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/HT209456)

Answer (score -1):

from the lock screen, the phone icon should be at the lower left, swipe up and it will take over the call from the mac.